# window.plugins.AdMob always undefined in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, admob, ionic-framework

I'm trying to include this [admob plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro).

I've tried everything, but whatever I do, the window.plugins.AdMob is always undefined. 
I checked it on my android device and also on the ios simulator (I know it's not working in the browser).

What I did: 
I added the plugin with the following command:
cordova plugin add com.google.cordova.admob

Then I tried following the instructions from the plugin, but also used the code example from [here](http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/).

But whatever I do, window.plugins.AdMob is always undefined.

I also tried loading it with a 3000ms timeout (because some answers say that the plugin is not initially ready and takes some time).

I really don't have a clue what to try next or what step I missed.
I also tried the google analytics plugin and followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/) but again, the "analytics" object is undefined. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using window.plugins.AdMob, please directly use AdMob, or window.AdMob.

It's defined in the plugin.xml:

```
<js-module src="www/AdMob.js" name="AdMob">
    <clobbers target="window.AdMob" />
</js-module>
```

The example code you see, is for the old AdMob plugin.

Comment: thanks alot! missed that somehow, working perfectly now! 
great plugin btw :)

Answer (score 1):

1.install admob phonegap plugin

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova
```

2. init admob plugin
   init plugin after deviceready event

   ```
    admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");
   ```

3.show admob ads

```
  admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_APP);//show banner at the top of app
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://github.com/Dharmoslap/ng-cordova. You can use AdMob Pro as well.